# upload multiple files via ajax jquery without form

Tags: ajax, file-upload, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a dialog box.The users have the option to upload files. I want to upload the files to server on clicking the button within the jquery dialog.I have tried many codes but unfortunately ,I cannot find the solution.Please help me.

My fiddle
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anazvak/xkot2vkn/2/)

**Jquery:**

```
$(function(){
 $(document).on('click','.click_link',function(){
 $("#dialog_loader").dialog("open");
$("#dialog_loader").css({'display':'show'});
return false;
});

$("#dialog_loader").dialog({resizable: false,
  height:"auto",
  modal: true,
  minWidth: 400,
  autoOpen:false,
  position: 'center top',
  buttons: {
    "Update": function() {
          var form_data = new FormData();
           $.each($("input[type='file']")[0].files, function(i, file) {
            form_data.append('file', file);
         });
        form_data.append("status", 'update');   
      $.ajax({
          url:path,
            type:'POST',
            dataType: "HTML",
            contentType : false,
            processData : false,
            data:form_data,
            success:function(msg){
               if(msg==1)
               {
                   alert(123);
               } 
            }
        });
    },
    "Approve":function(){

    },
    Cancel: function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
  }
});


$(document).on('click','.add_more',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var filePresent = document.getElementsByClassName('file')[document.getElementsByClassName('file').length-1].files.length;
if(filePresent >0  ){
    $(this).parent().find('#extra_file_div').find('.file_div_child').append("<br/><input name='file_uploads[]' type='file' class='multi_files file' /><button class='remove'>X</button>");
    //$(this).before("<div class='file_div_child'><input name='file_uploads[]' type='file' class='multi_files file' /><button class='remove'>X</button></div>");
  }  

});

$(document).on('change','input:file',
        function(){
            $('input:file').removeClass('multi_files');
        if ($(this).val()) {
            if($(this).parent().parent().find('.remove').length <1)
            {
                $(this).after("<button class='remove first_remove' >X</button>");
            }
            $('.add_more').show();
        } 
        else
        {
            $('.add_more').hide();

        }
    });

$(document).on('click','.remove',function(){
 var length = $('#dialog_attachments').find(".file").length; 
if(length > 1 ){
  $(this).prev('input:file').remove();
  $(this).prev('br').remove();
  $(this).remove();

 }
 else
 {
     $(".file").val('');
    $(this).remove();
    $(this).parent('.file_div_child').find('br').remove();
    $('.add_more').hide();
 }

 return false;
 }); 
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a form and put the file input parts inside that form element.
Then using jquery each function,I have added each file inputs to form_data object.

```
 var form_data = new FormData();
         var inputs = $(document).find("#file_form input");
        $.each(inputs, function (obj, v) {
             $.each($(v)[0].files, function(i, file) {
                        form_data.append(v.name, file);
                });
        });
        form_data.append("status", 'update');
```

I have updated the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let form_data = new FormData();
$.each($("input[type='file']")[0].files, function(i, file) {
    form_data.append('file[]', file);
})
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**